# SpringMVC4 Error Bad Request when on a Post with a select field

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am getting an 400 Error - Bad Request

Type Status Report

Description The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

The problem part on the form is comming from:

```
<form:select path="farm" required="required">
    <form:option value="NONE">--SELECT--</form:option>
    <form:options items="${farms}" itemValue="key" itemLabel="name"/>
</form:select>
```

this is the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveUser(@ModelAttribute User user) {
    if(user.getKey() == null) {
        user.setDateCreated(new Date());
        userService.addUser(user);
    }

    else userService.updateUser(user);

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/users");
}
```

If I remove the select everything works correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the value parameter inside select tag. Most of the times it creates a problem with the values containing hyphen or spaces etc.
E.g. value = "value - one" Browser doesn't recognize this. It should be like this value = "valueone" .
Inspect the page element on browser and verify the select tag option values.

Comment: the value parameter is fine

Comment: Okay! Have you tried to find out the problem using firebug?

Comment: actuinstead of farm,.ally I fixed it. It turns out the path ws wrong it should have been farm.key